# Define allowed users for telegram integration in API.ai

Tags: security, telegram, dialogflow-es

- Goal: Have a chat bot on telegram that only allows me to talk to my api.ai app
- Problem: Using the telegram bot integration, anyone with my bot ID could talk to it
- Expected: Some functionality to limit telegram user access by chat ID

Ive come to believe that this isn't possible right now (just using the telegram integration). I'd have to implement this myself, probably using the python SDK for api.ai. Problem is, their docs are nowhere to be found. Hope someone can help me realize this

Comment: Do you mean bot api or users api? Can you describe better your problem and expected results?

Comment: This is nothing to do with programming, please open ticket to your service provider

Comment: @sean I believe it does, it's a common developers tool for implementing NLP apps and there might be an answer involving code and the API.ai sdk